# How to print items in deque (python)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, collections, deque

I have this code:

```
import collections

def last3scores():
    return collections.deque([], 3)

user_last3 = collections.defaultdict(last3scores)

#after this I have some more code and then this:

user_last3[name].append(score)

print(str(user_last3))
```

But when I run the program, I get this:

```
defaultdict(<function last3scores at 0x0000000003806E18>, {'nick': deque([2], maxlen=3)})
```

What I'd like to get is this:

```
{'nick': [2]}
```

Is there a way to accomplish that in Python 3.* ?

Comment: You mean `{'nick': [2]}`? Is that the output you want?

Comment: `user_last3 = collections.defaultdict(last3scores)` you are building the dictionary with a function. `user_last3 = collections.defaultdict(last3scores())` call the function instead

Comment: @Mr.E, first argument of `defaultdict` must be callable. So it is correct.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini yea thats the one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick (in Python 3.* switch to `items` instead of `iteritems`):

```
>>> {k:list(v) for k,v in user_last3.iteritems()}
{'nick': [2]}
```

Comment: I got this:
    {k:list(v) for k,v in user_last3.iteritems()}
AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: switch with `items` instead of `iteritems` in python 3.*

Comment: I want to up 1 but I dont have a rep of 15 yet

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try following:

```
for key, value in user_last3.iteritems():
    print key, value
```

Comment: You'll have to apply `list()` to the `value`, otherwise you'll get the same string representation as shown in the question.